# Accessing a char in a vector of strings by its iterator

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

Here's a part of my code:

```
std::vector<std::string> syntax_words;
//...
//Currently the above vector contains few strings
std::vector<std::string>::iterator sy_iterator = syntax_words.begin(); 

while (sy_iterator != syntax_words.end(){
    if (*sy_iterator[4] == 'X'){
//...
```

Basically I want to access the fifth char in the current string. Unfortunately the above code is throwing an error during compilation:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::basic_string<char>’)
      if (*sy_iterator[4] == 'X'){
```

I've also tried this:

```
if (sy_iterator[4] == 'X'){
```

But it's also throwing an error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘char’)
      if (sy_iterator[sit] == 'X'){
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Precedence, precedence, precedence… what you meant is `(*sy_iterator)[4]` (or, equivalently, `sy_iterator->operator[](4)`).

Comment: Operator precedence, try `if ((*sy_iterator)[4] == 'X'){)
      `

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ohh, thank you. I forgot about that.

Comment: @user3125731 even if you forget it (because who can keep in mind all the precedences?) it's quite straightforward to deduce it from the compiler error message.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You're absolutely right. I have no idea why I didn't come up with the solution on my own. Maybe it's because I'm a little tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
while ( sy_iterator != syntax_words.end() )
{
    if ( sy_iterator->size() > 4 && ( *sy_iterator )[4] == 'X')
    {
        //...
```

The problem with your original code snippet is related to priorities of operators. Postfix operator [] has higher priority than unary operator *. Thus this expression

```
*sy_iterator[4]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( sy_iterator[4] )
```

Expression `sy_iterator[4]` will yield a string pointed to by iterator `sy_iterator + 4` to which you are trying to apply operator *. But class string has no operator *. So the compiler issues an error.

As for this statement

```
if (sy_iterator[4] == 'X'){
```

then here you are trying to compare iterator `sy_iterator + 4` with character literal `'X'`. Because there is no such an implicit conversion from one operand of the comparison to another operand then the compiler also issues an error.

Take into account that class std;:vector has rnadom access iterators so for example expression

```
syntax_words.begin() + 4
```

will yield fourth iterator relative to the itertor returned by member function begin().

Answer (score 1):

you can simply go like this:
[DEMO](http://ideone.com/SBdmc4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
        std::vector<std::string> syntax_words;
        syntax_words.push_back("urs X is here");
    for (string str : syntax_words){
      if(str.size() > 5 && str.at(4) == 'X')
        cout << "found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```